# save dialog javascript firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, dialog, save

Following code finds all links with in ul li and get their href image path and add event so when user click on link it opens save dialog. This only works in Internet Explorer. How can I do this for other browsers. Note: I want this feature with out using any server e.g. php, jsp, asp etc.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $anchors = $("ul li a").each(function (i) {
        if($(this).attr('href').indexOf("jpg") > -1 || $(this).attr('href').indexOf("jpeg") > -1 || $(this).attr('href').indexOf("gif") > -1 || $(this).attr('href').indexOf("png") > -1){
            image_path = $(this).attr('href');
            if($.browser.msie){
                $(this).attr('href',"javascript:void(0);");
                $(this).click(function() { 
                    win = window.open(image_path,'win');
                    window.setTimeout('check();',1000);
                    return false; 
                });
            }
            else
            {
                // code for other browsers
            }
        }
    });
});

var win = null;
var image_path = null;
function check() {
    if (win.document.readyState=='complete'){
        win.document.execCommand("SaveAs");
        win.close();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout('check();',1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you willing to use flash or do you want an all JS/HTML solution?  I wanted some pdfs to download directly and not be handled by the web browser. I had to set a property on the pdf file itself if I remember correctly. It basically told the browser to not handle it and just download it. So, do you have control over the images?

Comment: Yes its ok if we do this using flash technique. But this should be a small code that I can include in html pages and do not changes any thing else. Above code is embedded at the end of jquery and that file is included into html and it start working in IE. I need similar solution that works stand alone.